# Intersection of tetrahedral and triangular mesh

Tags: python, mesh, triangular

I hava a tetrahedral mesh which is described by nodes [x,y,z] and elements/cells [node1, node2, node3, node4]. I also have a triangular (surface) mesh described by nodes[x,y,z] and elements/cells [node1, node2, node3].
The goal is to find those tetrahedral elements which are intersected by the triangular mesh.

[example of two meshes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8Ulw.png)

Comment: This task is yours to implement. If you don't care about speed, just iterate all tetrahedral  elements and check intersection with every triangle

Comment: Though you’ve mentioned python, you haven’t included your current code. It’ll be easier to get help if you share what you have so far.

Comment: Some spatial optimizations by splitting the world into chunks could be applied to reduce number of comparisons, but it's by far harder to implement